# Adding CORS in HAPROXY 1.6.9 with rspadd headers

Tags: haproxy

I have setup HAPROXY on top of Apache which is working fine but I am not able make api call from other domain, It was CORS issues so I added

rspadd Access-Control-Allow-Origin:\ *

But still it is not adding response headers in api call.
Please let me know. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Here is my whole haproxy.cfg file

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local2
    #log 127.0.0.1  local1 notice
    #log loghost    local0 info
    #log /dev/log local0 info
    log-tag haproxy
    maxconn 4096
    chroot /usr/share/haproxy
    uid 99
    gid 99
    daemon
    debug
    #quiet

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    redispatch
    maxconn 2000
    contimeout  5000
    clitimeout  5000
    srvtimeout  5000

frontend https
    #bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/server.bundle.pem
    option http-buffer-request
      declare capture request len 400000
      http-request capture req.body id 0
      log-format {"%[capture.req.hdr(0)]"}
    # /opt/causeway/etc/libwebsockets-cpa.pem
    acl httpsapi path_beg /API
    use_backend serv_https_api if httpsapi
    default_backend default_apache

frontend http
    bind *:80
    #bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/server.bundle.pem
    acl api path_beg /api
    use_backend serv_api if api
    default_backend default_apache

backend default_apache
    server apache 127.0.0.1:81

backend serv_api
    server server1 127.0.0.1:7687
    rspadd Access-Control-Allow-Origin:\ *
    rspadd Access-Control-Max-Age:\ 31536000

backend serv_https_api
    server server2 127.0.0.1:7687
    rspadd Access-Control-Allow-Origin:\ *
    rspadd Access-Control-Max-Age:\ 31536000
    # mode tcp
    # log global
    # tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    # tcp-request content accept if { req.ssl_hello_type 1 }
```

Any help highly appriciated.

Comment: With your configuration, I get a HTTP response with the correct headers. Did you reload/restart HAProxy ? Are you using the correct url (one starting with `/api/`) ?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I was getting 504 error, that was timeout problem from server. This error response was not having CORs header.